# Trying to delete user from database by Username in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# MVC and am having trouble figuring out how to make the connection to the specific user I am trying to delete.

I have a table that reads the users in by username (user.UserName)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
 {
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @user.UserName
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    var roleId = user.UserRoles != null && user.UserRoles.Any() ? user.UserRoles.First().RoleId : (short) 2;
                }

                @Html.DropDownList(string.Format("User_{0}", user.UserId), ListProvider.GetRoles(roleId), new {})
                <input type="button" data-id="@user.UserId" value="Set" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-set"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I then have a DeleteUser Action in my controller, which links to a delete user method.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(string usernameToDelete)
    {
        var deleteUserObj = new User {UserName = usernameToDelete};
        UsersContext deleteUser = new UsersContext();
        deleteUser.DeleteUser(deleteUserObj);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Complete DeleteUser method in Context:

```
public void DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        Users.Remove(user);
        SaveChanges();
    }
```

What I don't understand is how to connect the usernameToDelete to the specific user.Username that I am trying to delete.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete a user, you need to get that user not creating a new instance of the `User` object.

This needs to change:

```
var deleteUserObj = new User {UserName = usernameToDelete};
```

To something like:

```
var deleteUserObj = UserContext.LoadItemByUsername(usernameToDelete);
```

Where `LoadItemByUsername` is a method that checks the db to find a user using the username.

The problem you can have is that searching on a username could have more results, if your column is not set for unique values.

A more proper way to achieve this is using the Id of the user. Then using this primary key you can directly delete the user object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
{
    UsersContext deleteUser = new UsersContext();
    deleteUser.Delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Where `deleteUser.Delete(id);` is the method that requires the PK of the user to delete the object.

**UPDATE**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "ControllerName", new { id = user.UserId })">Delete user</a>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
public void DeleteUser(int id)
{
    User delObj = Users.Where(u => u.UserId == id);
    Users.Remove(delObj);
    SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I am still unsure how to make the connection to the specific user that is in the same row as the delete button since the usernames are just read out in a foreach loop.

Comment: View update, instead of using a submit use a hyperlink to delete the user. I don't now your name of your controller but you can change that in the code. Also remove the `[HttpPost]` tag above your controller method because its a GET action instead of POST instead.

Comment: Awesome, then I will have to change the delete user method in my UsersContext?                                                                                                          public void DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            Users.Remove(user);
            SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: Jup to allow the id of the user so you now which one to delete, view my answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm  just trying to understand how to change the delete method in UsersContext to now remove a user by id. Sorry for all the questions, I'm very new with this.

Comment: No problem, just do it step by step and you will get it. Can you show me the code you have in your context to remove the user?

Comment: can you show your completely context in your question? So its better to read

Comment: Done, I am just unsure how to change this method to work with your solution